# TypeError: Data location must be "storage" or "memory" for parameter in function, but none was given

Tags: solidity, remix, storage, memory

```
/// @dev Adds a new transaction to the transaction mapping, if transaction does not exist yet.
/// @param destination Transaction target address.
/// @param value Transaction ether value.
/// @param data Transaction data payload.
/// @return Returns transaction ID.
function addTransaction(address destination, uint value, bytes data)
    internal
    returns (uint transactionId)
{
    transactionId = transactionCount;
    transactions[transactionId] = Transaction({
        destination: destination,
        value: value,
        data: data,
        executed: false
    });
    transactionCount += 1;
    Submission(transactionId);
}
```

In In  function addTransaction(address destination, uint value, bytes data)

With underlined  the byte data parameter

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As of Solidity 0.5.0. https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html

> Explicit data location for all variables of struct, array or mapping types is now mandatory. This is also applied to function parameters and return variables. For example, change uint[] x = m_x to uint[] storage x = m_x, and function f(uint[][] x) to function f(uint[][] memory x) where memory is the data location and might be replaced by storage or calldata accordingly. Note that external functions require parameters with a data location of calldata.

You can fix it by saying `memory` for the `bytes` argument which is an array of `byte`.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract Memory {
    function addTransaction(address destination, uint value, bytes memory data)
        internal
        returns (uint transactionId)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Warnings are safe to ignore. I wanted to keep this example as close as possible to the original and confirm it compiles.

Answer (score 5):

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract Election {
    // Model a candidate
    struct Candidate{
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    // Store candidate
    //Read/write Candidates
    mapping(uint => Candidate) public candidates;

    // Store Cnadidates Count
    uint public candidatesCount;

   constructor () public {
      addCandidate("Candidate 1");
      addCandidate("Candidate 2");
      addCandidate("Candidate 3");
      addCandidate("Candidate 4");
    }

    function addCandidate (string memory _name) private {
        candidatesCount ++;
        candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, _name, 0);

     }
}
```

Comment: This is a code only answer. Provide explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For function parameter and return variables explicit data location for all variables (`struct`, `array of mappings`, `string`) are mandatory. You can also fix by saying `string memory` for he `bytes` argument.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;

contract MyContract {
   function addTransaction(address destination, uint value, string memory data) 
   public 
{
    /* My Code ...*/
}
```