# why a parameter must be "storage" or "memory"?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage, memory

I am creating a token like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "../utils/math/SafeMath.sol";


contract ExampleDivisibleNFTs {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    // Percentage of ownership over a token  
    mapping(address => mapping(string => uint)) ownerToTokenShare;

    // If a token has been created
    mapping(string => bool) mintedToken;

    modifier onlyNonExistentToken(string _tokenId) {
        require(mintedToken[_tokenId] == false, "the NFT already exists");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyExistentToken(string _tokenId) {
        require(mintedToken[_tokenId] == true, "the NFT doesn't exists");
        _;
    }

}
```

and I am testing with [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org) but I have the following problem

**Data location must be "storage" or "memory" for parameter in function, but none was given.**

```
modifier onlyNonExistentToken(string _tokenId) {
                              ^-------------^
```

why a parameter may to be a "storage", It is not always "memory" ?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63294/typeerror-data-location-must-be-storage-or-memory-for-parameter-in-function

Comment: Since storage and memory have different costs it is better to explicitely declare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solidity compiler requires an explicit declaration of the data location for persistency and semantic reasonings. 
With that being said, in your particular smart contract, the `_tokenID` string is passed by reference and because of the fact that the reference --> points to your `mintedToken` mapping, then it’s a reference to storage which is why the compiler begs you to explicitly declare it as such.

Answer (score 0):

**memory** is to be used with an array, struct, string, and mapping, I guess it's the desired default expected by solidity. You can use the **storage** at the expense of your gas.